# Database Access in Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

How to insert the database access column in combobox, on button click?it has 1 column

Comment: do  you want insert data into the database....?

Comment: maybe you should try to improve your question. it's not clear what you're asking us to help you with.

Comment: ok, i have a multiple database access with table and column and one combobox on buttonclick in combobox change the database

Comment: Are you asking how to choose a database in a combo, and then connect to it for the rest of the form?

Comment: ex: buttonclick 1 combobox = databaseusers, buttonclick2 combobox = databasestudent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

create a private method that get msaccess data and bind to a datatable:

```
private DataTable BindData()
        {
            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\YOURDB.mdb; PersSecurity Info=False;")) /your connectionsting
            {
                using (var dAd = new OleDbDataAdapter("select ID,column1 from Table ", conn)) //select query from your DB
                {

                    var dSet = new DataTable();
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();

                        dAd.Fill(dSet);

                        return dSet;

                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Then on your button click Add

```
        var dt = BindData();
        cmbBox.DataSource = dt;
        cmbBox.DisplayMember = "column1"; //Display Table Column on your DB
        cmbBox.ValueMember = "ID";
```

See also:

[The C# Station ADO.NET Tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson01.aspx)

Regards

Comment: c# sharp and visual studio 2010 sp1

Comment: sorry, i have another question..it is possible associate at column1 ex: name on the column 2 ex; ID? use the cmbbox.valuemember =

Comment: thanks but i have tested with Messagebox.show(cmbBox.ValueMember); and return this text: ID

Comment: I remember myself like you before .. :)